# rawtypes compiler warning on generic array creation

Tags: java, generics, javac

I do understand, that one cannot create array of generic class in java, e.g.

```
  private static final Class<String>[] ARGUMENT_TYPE = new Class<String>[]{String.class};
```

So I have used the raw type:

```
  private static final Class[] ARGUMENT_TYPE = new Class[]{String.class};
```

But now java compiler complains

> warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Class
>
> private static final Class[] ARGUMENT_TYPE = new Class[]{String.class};

Is there any way aside from `SuppressWarnings` to say to the compiler: "shut up, I have to do this by your own specification!"

Comment: Why not using a `List<Class<String>>`? Arrays and generics do not combine well ... By the way: What purpose does `Class<String>` have? Why not `Class<?>`?

Comment: Because I do know that I have `Class<String>`. It seems strange to use `?`.

Comment: And we use arrays because 3rd party library expects `Class[]`

Comment: I think the strange thing is that there should only ever be one instance of `Class<String>` so why have an array with numerous entries that should all point to the same object? Are you sure your 3rd party library doesn't expect a plain old `String[]` instead?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure how you plan to use this static array.  Some additional context would be nice.

How about this?

```
private static final Class<?>[] ARGUMENT_TYPE = new Class<?>[]{String.class, Int.class};
```

Comment: This looks exactly like the intended usage. But again, that `?` looks strange to me :( Why on Earth compiler forces me to write it?

Comment: Sorry but as you can already see in the example code, it is now possible to add Class objects for different classes. That is not exactly what you asked for (`Class<String>[]`).

Comment: @Nikem, I think the compiler is merely making sure you intend to use the generic without specifying a type.  It's a kind of shorthand for an ignore warning directive.  Using a generic class as if it were a regular class without explicitly telling the compiler that's what you intend is a red flag that you made a mistake.  Granted, in this case it only makes sense to use an array of unknown Class objects, or your array could only contain one class object, which would defeat the purpose of arrays.  But I imagine it would be quite a task to get the compiler to be quite that smart.